# Executing SQL Statements from a Text File

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have data base problems due to miss organized

to solve this problem i have to run 137073 mysql queries

this is the query sample

```
update wp_posts set post_author = replace(post_author, '43', '235099');
```

i create a text file contain 137073 line what is best way to run this queries one by one as a script or some thing

Thanks

Comment: Are you replacing `137073` numbers? `43` is not replacing forty three.

Comment: do you have access to command line mysql?  or do you have phpMyAdmin?

Comment: no i am replacing 43 with 235099 and 137071 it total quires number

Comment: i have phpMyAdmin access

Comment: I mean if `post_author` is full of integers, `143`, `243`, etc, the `43` there will also be replaced with `235099`.

Comment: The dupe target is about loading a .sql with browse / import / go. Ignore the thing "the other guy" is doing. Focus on how one runs a script with that dupe target